# Zend Framework loads mappers from Application/Model/ instead of application/models

Tags: zend-framework, class, frameworks, directory, mapper

My zend app is created, everything seems to be in order but every time I try to do something like:

$accProducts = new Application_Models_AccProductsMapper();

Only get:

Warning: include_once(Application/Models/AccProductsMapper.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/blah/blah/blah/Loader.php on line 148

however, the AccProductsMapper.php file do exist in such directory, directories within the zend app are all lowercase tough.

I've spend a lot of time looking for something to solve this issue with no good results at all.

---

Bootstrap.php

```
<?php

class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initDoctype()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('view');
        $view = $this->getResource('view');
        $view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');
    }

    protected function _initAutoload()
    {
        $moduleLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => '',
            'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH));
        $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
        $autoloader->registerNamespace(array('App','My_'));
        return $moduleLoader;
    }
}
```

Comment: Reaname your dirs. You should work as though they are case sensitive (even if they are not on your system). Additionally you can count on all the inflection in Zend to use CamelCase.

Comment: Thanks dude! but it doesn't work... only get a blank screen...
I've seen in other controllers that the way to call the mapper is something like:

$var = new Application_Model_AccProductsMapper();

which seems to be ridicuolus b/c the so called 'Model' simply doesn't exist, but the 'models' one do
am i doing something wrong???

Also i've seen in many posts that they use modules, so far i don't have any, using modules is a must???

Comment: You try to create an instance of `Application_Models_AccProductsMapper` while the class should be names `Application_Model_AccProductsMapper` (mind the difference of Model and Models). It is the **plural** version lowercase which is the folder where you place the capitalized **singular** version. So the class `Foo_Model_Bar` is located in `Foo/models/Bar.php`.

Comment: @Jurian Sluiman yes, that's right, either singular or plural gets the same result: nothing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard `Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource` class added to each module looks for models with the class prefix `<ModuleNamespace>_Model_` in `<module-directory>/models`.

For the default module, the namespace is defined in your config's `appnamespace` property (defaults to `Application`). The directory is typically `application`.

To summarize, create your default module model classes in `application/models` with class prefix `Application_Model_`, eg

```
<?php
// application/models/AccProductsMapper.php

class Application_Model_AccProductsMapper
{
    // etc
```

---

As for your `_initAutoload()` method, I can't tell what you're doing with that module loader and would advise you don't need it at all. You can register PEAR style namespaces in your config file, eg

```
autoloadernamespaces.App = "App_"
autoloadernamespaces.My = "My_"
```

Comment: that's exactly how the structure of my project is right now, same directories, same prefix and same class name but still getting the same warning "failed to open stream"; btw i used the _initAutoload() function in my Bootstrap.php file using the APPLICATION_PATH as basePath

Comment: @CABP Your question says otherwise. In your question your class name uses `Models` (plural). It should be `Model` (singular). Can you post your `_initAutoload()` method? There's not usually any reason to customise the autoloader unless you're adding other autoloaders into the stack

Comment: @CABP I've moved your code into your question. See my updated answer

Comment: thanks dude! that's just great! i'll follow your advice =)  About the problem i had... well i have to admit that it was my mistake and an infant one, just changed file permissions and it's working now, thanks a lot!!!